# FormatMessageV() of CString replaces \n with \r\n

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, variadic-functions, line-endings

There is a function called as [`FormatMessageV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170#formatmessagev) which is part of `CString` class that is supposed to 'Format a message string using a variable argument list' according to MSDN.
Other than the said operation unfortunately it also replaces `\n` in the message with `\r\n` which I don't want.

I tried to pass the ASCII value of LF instead of `\n` in the message but not surprisingly that didn't alter the routine's behaviour. I couldn't come across anything online which mentions about why this happens and how to prevent it.

Does any of you good folks here have any idea about this? Following is a minimum reproducible example, unfortunately, I couldn't find any free online Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to run the sample and link, but it prints `Has CR in it!` on my machine in the Visual Studio C+ project.

```
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <iostream>
 
CString FormatV(LPCTSTR first, ...)
{
 
    va_list vaList = nullptr;
    CString buffer;
    va_start(vaList, first);
    buffer.FormatMessageV(first, &vaList); //this adds \r before \n
    va_end(vaList);
 
    return buffer;
}
 
 
int main() 
{
    CString text = L"\nint Fun(LPCTSTR commandLine, UINT number)\n{ Perform(commandLine,% 1); \n }"; // Notice that it has only \n s
    CString formattedText = FormatV(text, 1); //formattedText has \r\n s
    if (formattedText.Find(L'\r', 0) != -1)
        std::cout << "Has CR in it!";
}
```

Comment: How do you know it replaces newline with the CR-NL pair? How do you check? Have you used a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to check the actual contents of the string? Are you sure it's actually in the string itself and not just an artifact of printing or writing to a text console or file, where such translations usually happen?  Please try to show us a [mre] of your test-case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I used the Visual Studio 2022 debugger to come to that conclusion. Let me try to produce a minimal reproducible example and update the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added the minimal reproducible example. Can you reopen the question please.

Comment: Since [`FormatMessageV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#formatmessagev) calls [`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) have you tried using `%n` in place of `\n`?

Comment: @IInspectable no, let me try that! Edit: Unfortunately, %n in place of \n didn't make any difference.

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage. It's a pretty complicated function. Otherwise just transform `\r\n` back into`\n` after calling `FormatMessageV`.

Comment: Looks like a property of `FormatMessage`. If you don't want that, use [`CString::FormatV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#formatv) which calls the standard `vsprintf_s` CRT function.

Comment: @ZoomIn are you sure you need `FormatMessage` in the first place?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah, that was my workaround to just transform CRLF to LF after calling FormatMessageV. But this function is called at so many places, so I have to do that multiple times which would be cumbersome. And I would need FormatMessage because at different places I would need to 'place' a different number of arguments in the 'message'.

Comment: What specific feature of `FormatMessage` do you need that isn't available with [`vsprintf_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf)?

Comment: @IInspectable I tried your first idea which was CString::FormatV. That approach ends up with Debug Assertion Failed ("'n' format specifier disabled",0)  in __stdio_common_vswprintf of cstringt.h. W.R.t, your question, I am not sure as this is an existing code but I will try if I can achieve the same with vsprintf_s.

Comment: The debug assertion reads like you have a (non-standard) `%n` in your format string. `%n` works with `FormatMessageV` (based on `FormatMessage`) but not with `FormatV` (based on `vsprintf_s`).

Comment: (commandLine,% 1). Typo here?

Comment: @TomTom Yeah, it's a typo.

Comment: Worked more than 15 years with MFC, and don't remember a single time I used such `FormatMessageV` or similar function...

Comment: @sergiol `FormatMessageV` (and `FormatMessage`) support positional arguments, frequently used when localizing applications. To my knowledge none of the `printf`-style formatting functions support positional arguments. They were introduced as recent as C++20 ([`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)).